# Скопировать все файлы

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно скопировать все файлы, имена которых начинается с "stat" (есть примерно 500 файлов типа stat1.txt stat2.txt ..)? Думаю нужно будет использовать регулярные выражения. Было бы хорошо, если бы код был на QT.

Comment: Смотрите [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) и [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex)

Comment: Это разовая акция? Если да, то легче readdir() + strstr()

Comment: @NewView Всм разовая акция?

Answer (score 1):

QtIterator'ом обходишь директорию и собираешь нужные файлы. (Можно использовать QFile или QFileInfo для работы с текущим файлом.)